# Can you pull content from a neighboring column of a reference in excel?

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have two sheets. One that lists all of my projects with columns for client, project number, project name, and etc. And one that I use to track estimated hours for the people on the project.

I want to be able select the project name in the first column on the hours sheet and have it populate the next couple of columns with the related data from the project sheet so I only have to maintain each project's details in one spot.

Right now I have the project name column on the hour sheet creating a list of the project names from the projects sheet but can't seem to find the worksheet function/formula to have it pull the other data in based on the one selection.

Any insight on how to do this would be very helpful.

Comment: You should give more details if you really want the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have one Hours Sheet for all projects or a Hours Sheet for each project?

Let's assume you have the following sheet's structure in your Excel:

Projects | MyProject1 hours | MyProject2 hours | MyProject3 hours

If I understood your question, your goal is to have a dropdown combobox in your Projects (main) sheet that takes data from the hours sheets according to the project selected, right?

Therefore, we'd have a combobox in Projects with the values MyProject1 / MyProject2 / MyProject3.

It's fairly simple using vlookup Excel formula. You'll need to ensure all project sheets have the same structure, though.

Still, if you have only one sheet with hours + a column identifying the project, is still feasible with vlookup, but will be a little bit harder.

These are the Excel formulas you may need to use:

```
 - =VLOOKUP(...)
 - =MATCH(...)
 - =INDIRECT(...)
```

Once I understand better your question, I might be able to help a little bit more.

Rgds

**Edit #1:**

Is this the expected workflow?

- Project Details are entered manually into ProjectOne sheet (Client, Number, Name)
- The project name (ProjectOne) is added manually into the first column of sheet Hours
- This first column populates a combobox containing the project names (ProjectOne, ProjectTwo, ProjectThree)
- You select the value ProjectOne in this combobox (in Hours sheet)
- The values from ProjectOne sheet are retrieved into Hours sheet
- You edit the values (in Hours sheet) and these changes are applied back into ProjectOne sheet

It sounds confusing to me, I'm sorry. Maybe if you give us column headers for both sheets, or the expected data flow (what is supposed to be done manually / automatically).

Otherwise, you'll need to wait for another guy that understands your request better than I did. :)

Comment: The structure would be more like "Hours | Projects" Where hours has all our team members with their hours per project defined by week. Then the hours sheet would have a drop down to select a project and populate the other info needed. I will look into those functions you mentioned as well.

Comment: Offtopic, but would worth to have a look: Toggl. Very good time management tool, and is free for up to 5 team members.

Comment: The doc I am building is hour forecasting, not tracking. Also VLOOKUP is working, just not always pulling the correct row. I will play a little more and post an update later.

Comment: @gokujou use the last parameter of vlookup as FALSE. It may fix your problem with not returning the correct row sometimes.

Comment: gokujou great! I'm just curious to know if you used the formulas above :D